# When I need to write explicitly "initializer list" in constructors?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initializer-list

I don't understand when I need to write myself the "initializer list" in constructors? I reed about it in some tutorials but it's still not clear how to work with this.

(I understood that the fields of class must be initialized before  the execution of the function body. But some details are missing and it's not clear when can I need to write the "initializer list" myself, and when I can to trust the "hidden initializer list" that executed by the default constructor of any field)

Comment: @Ron Ok, I meant to ask, when I need to write it at all (cases that it's "must" and I can't trust the default constructor of any field).

Comment: For classes with private members, you always need to write it - classes don't magically initialise themselves.

Comment: You want us to enumerate all of those cases?

Comment: @StoryTeller No, Of course. But to get a some rules about it and by this get the instinct..

Comment: @StoryTeller In fact, now, I see (in the related link that "Drew Dormann" added ) this rule: `if a class doesn't have a default constructor, or you have a const member variable, you must use an initializer list` (This is can be a good answer [I don't know if it's a full answer or not , but anyway it's give a some instinct] for my question)

Comment: @NeilButterworth Are you sure that it's correct? if to this private members exist a default constructor?

Comment: Yes, if there is a default constructor for those types, they will be initialised without you doing anything. But  many (most?) types don't have a default constructor.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Right, ok, thank you for your help!